# sending data with attachment doesn't work Cronjob

Tags: php, phpmailer, cron, attachment

I dont know alot about cron job but i have a php file which sending data with attachment when i run it using the browser it's working fine and attachment is sent ,but if i use cron job to run it ,it never goes with the attachment.
here is the cron job command-line :

```
/opt/php54/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/to/myscript.php
```

and here is the place of error in the php file ,as the cron job sending me email with "Some how file :hhshd.jpg is not exist!" , however the data with attachment is sent successfully when i use the browser.

```
 if (!file_exists("uploads/" .  $fileName))
            {
                die("Some how file :$fileName is not exist!");
            }
```

Note: i am using the cronjob of Hostgator.

Comment: When you ask a question about an error **ALWAYS** include the **error log**. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your `php` script, what does it return? Also, you may want to use the full path to `$fileName`

Comment: @PedroLobito
i have mentioned the error ...the only message i got through the email , is the file is not exist , also i have tried to include the full path like :
"/home2/nh75group/public_html/old-soon/SMTtest/uploads/ .  $fileName"
but it doesn't work with me even when i run the php file through the browser, So i think i am using wrong full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved i have used this cron job command:

```
curl http://yoursite/path/to/publish.php
```

Comment: Upvoted as this worked for me, however I would caution that using CURLis potentially dangerous because it requires you to open up your script to http traffic and potential attacks.  As an aside, most Wordpress files begin with defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit; as a method to prevent script execution if the file is accessed directly.  This won't work with CURL.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason cold be when you run the script through browser, the Apache user is able to create the attachment file and send it.

But when cronjob is not able to create attachment file due to permission issue.

You can try using 'sudo' in your cronjob or try changing the permission of the directory where you are creating the attachment.

Comment: can you please be more specific, as i am totally new to cronjob ,So how to use Sudo ,like what will be the new cronjob?

Comment: try using 

sudo /opt/php54/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/to/myscript.php

Comment: when i put the mentioned Command line , it gives :

"sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?"

Comment: You may try changing the folder permissions. It would be quicker and better, as depending upon your setup, sudo may also required password to be entered which will not be available in cron.

Comment: i have made it readable,wirtealbe and excutable to all , and still the same error.

let me mention that ,when i used (https://cron-job.org/) it worked fine also and the attachment went fine,but it's never worked with hostgator cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely to be an ownership & permissions problem. What you have to put in your cron config depends on where you've put it and what user your web server runs as. If you want it to run at 5am each day, it's in `/etc/crontab` and `www-data` is your web server user, you would need an entry like this:

```
0 5    * * *   www-data    /opt/php54/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/to/myscript.php
```

If it's in the web server user's own crontab file, it would skip the user name field. You would edit it using `crontab -u www-data -e`, and add a line like this:

```
0 5 * * * /opt/php54/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/to/myscript.php
```

One other issue may be that the current working directory may be different, so you may need to set the command to include a `cd` to the directory your script is in first, like this:

```
cd /home/username/public_html/path/to && /opt/php54/bin/php myscript.php
```

If you want to receive any error output from a cron job, set a `MAILTO` environment variable by adding a line like this to the cron file before you run the command:

```
MAILTO=user@example.com
```

Comment: when i used the command :
0 5    * * *   www-data    /opt/php54/bin/php /home/username/public_html/path/to/myscript.php

it gives :
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: www-data: command not found

i am using hostgator cronjob...so i dont have access to any configuration only write down the command line .

let me mention that ,when i used (https://cron-job.org/) it worked fine also and the attachment went fine,but it's never worked with hostgator cronjob.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like it's not a proper cron job at all, just some other thing. It's worth trying just the command string with the `cd` in.

Comment: i have tried this command line:
cd /home/username/public_html/path/to && /opt/php54/bin/php myscript.php

and now i got an error of:
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home2/username/public_html/path/to/myscript.php on line 229

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home2/username/public_html/path/to/myscript.php on line 229

Comment: i have fix this error and now i got that message has been sent successfully as happening when i run it on browser ,but  i still receive the message without attachment!!

Comment: here the received response from (cron-job.org):

Server: nginx/1.12.0
Date: Sat, 29 Apr 2017 03:22:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=fe58147ce49525dee03b26f8ec7d0a47; path=/

Comment: Don't put code in comments; edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

*** * * * * curl http://localhost/Android/SMS/p1.php**

type above line to execute every second p1.php email sending file with attachment.
p1.php file is in my htdocs/Android/SMS folder.